# MySQL stored procedure no values retrieve

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I had migrated a stored procedure from Sql Server to Mysql, and I´ve created with *phpmyadmin routines*, the syntax is ok, but when I execute stored procedure, doesn't return any value.

```
DROP PROCEDURE `sp_buscar`; CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_buscar`(IN `@buscar` VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER

SELECT idColono AS Folio, nombreColono as Nombre, CONCAT(apellidoP ,' ', apellidoM) as Apellido,  CONCAT(domicilio,'  ', numero) as Dirección,  numeroTel AS Telefono 
FROM cColonos 
WHERE domicilio LIKE CONCAT (@buscar, '%')
```

In Sql Server it works with no problem.

```
CREATE PROC sp_buscar
@buscar VARCHAR(50)
AS
SELECT idColono AS Folio, nombreColono as Nombre, apellidoP +' '+ apellidoM as Apellido,  domicilio+'  '+ numero as Dirección,  numeroTel AS Telefono
FROM cColonos
WHERE domicilio LIKE  @buscar + '%'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Show you mysql stored proc not the one from sql svr

Comment: @Drew The first code is from Mysql, I used Routines tool from phpmyadmin. Let me edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION!**

```
DROP PROCEDURE `sp_buscar`; CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_buscar`(IN `buscar` VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER

SELECT idColono AS Folio, nombreColono as Nombre, 
       CONCAT(apellidoP ,' ', apellidoM) as Apellido,  
       CONCAT(domicilio,'  ', numero) as Dirección,  
       numeroTel AS Telefono 
FROM cColonos 
WHERE domicilio LIKE CONCAT(buscar, '%')
```

I just had delete **@** from buscar var and it works!

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the space after `concat`:

```
SELECT idColono AS Folio, nombreColono as Nombre,
       CONCAT(apellidoP ,' ', apellidoM) as Apellido,
       CONCAT(domicilio,'  ', numero) as Dirección,
       numeroTel AS Telefono 
FROM cColonos 
WHERE domicilio LIKE CONCAT(@buscar, '%');
```

MySQL has a parsing problem with spaces after function names.

This rather unusual restriction is actually [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html):

> Note
>
> By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and
>   the parenthesis following it. This helps the MySQL parser distinguish
>   between function calls and references to tables or columns that happen
>   to have the same name as a function. However, spaces around function
>   arguments are permitted.

And there is a system parameter that allows spaces.

Comment: Still not working, even I tried this **WHERE domicilio LIKE @buscar**,  without CONCAT, and no retrieve values, and yes, the table has like 500 records. Anyway thank you man.